# Toggle heart shaped html code in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a heart shaped icon as a button.
On a click of it should toggle filled/non-filled.
I got two - ♡ and ❤
But when I am comparing it as a text. I cant. Because it appears as an image.
Here is my try:

```
function setMyFavorite(){
 alert('SetMyFavorite for '+ $("#heart").html());
 if($("#heart").html()=="&#9825;"){
    $("#heart").html("&#10084;");
 }

 if($("#heart").html()=="&#10084;"){
        $("#heart").html("&#9825;");
 }
}
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<div id="heart" title="Set as Favorite" onclick="javascript:setMyFavorite();">&#9825;</div>
```

How Can I compare it?

Comment: Could you please also attach your html code? That might be helpfull to solve your problem.

Comment: If you are not using any third part css like FontAwesome and wants to do it only Js then you can add data attribute flag to `<div>` based on which you compare heart type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compare using the unicode characters.

```js
const whiteHeart = '\u2661';
const blackHeart = '\u2665';
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', toggle);

function toggle() {
  const like = button.textContent;
  if(like==whiteHeart) {
    button.textContent = blackHeart;
  } else {
    button.textContent = whiteHeart;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>♡</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

**add Html buttons like this**

```
<div>
  <i class="heart fa fa-heart-o"></i>
</div>
```

**Add CSS For this button**

```
.heart {
  font-size: 25px;
    color:red;
}
```

**Javascript to select and unselect button**

```
$(".heart.fa").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("fa-heart fa-heart-o");
});
```

check jsfiddle demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/69ww31n3/)

Comment: Adding a whole new library (albeit a cool library) when it isn't needed, seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

best way to do this is : use font awesome icons in button.

there are 2 types icons solid/light which you can use in your case.

so on toggle you can replace class of font awesome.

EX. this is your button
 `<button class="fa fa-heart"></button>`

So on toggle you just need to replace the class of button

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will give you some idea :) have fun!

JavaScript:

```
<script>
function setMyFavorite(){
var elem = document.getElementById("circle");
//Gets the RGB value
var theColor = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
var hex = rgb2hex(theColor);
 if(hex =="#555555"){
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
 }
else if(hex =="#ffffff"){
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "#555555";
}
//Convert RGB to Hex value
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    function hex(x) {
        return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}
</script>
```

CSS:

```
 background-color: #555;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border-color:#555;
 border-style: solid;
```

Comment: Add some description